# How can I make Travis CI use input() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, travis-ci

I'm just learning python and am making a simple text game, I have this in it: `cave = input()`, How can I get Travis to enter something?

Comment: You can't. You should probably use an environment variable

Comment: use environment variable or text file with inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶d̶e̶l̶e̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶`̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶(̶)̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶I̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶ ̶I̶ ̶m̶a̶d̶e̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶e̶s̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶

A better way is to use the environment variables, so you just change the travis.yml file.

For example change `cave = input()` to `cave = os.eviron['cave']` when in your tavis.yml file it says

```yaml
env:
  global:
    - cave=4
```

Don't forget to `import os` at the start of your script.